# How many numbers from first string are in other string on the different position

Tags: c

I do not know how to solve this problem, this function.

**peg_a = how many numbers from *secret are in *guess on the same position.**

Example: *secret = "1234" | *guess = "1289"| ... peg_a = 2.

**peg_b = how many numbers from *secret are in *guess but on the different position.**

Example: *secret = "1234" | *guess = "8912"| ... peg_b = 2.

---

My problem: If I have secret ... "2211" and guess "1002" ... peg_b is 4, it need to be 2 (because they are 2 same numbers in secret, but on the other position) ... how to solve this problem?

Sorry for my english and programming skills.

```
 void get_score(char* secret, char* guess, int* peg_a, int* peg_b)
    {
    int i, j;
    int pa, pb;
    pa = pb = 0;
    int lens = strlen(secret);
    int leng = strlen(guess);
    for(i = 0; i < lens; i++)
      {
        if(secret[i] == guess[i])
           {
           pa++;
           continue;
           }
        for(j = 0; j < leng; j++)
        {  
          if((secret[i] == guess[j]) && (secret[j] != guess[j]))
          {
            pb++;
          }
        }
      }

      *peg_a = pa;
      *peg_b = pb; 
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a numeric [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)).

Comment: Once `pb++;` occurs, break out of the `for(j)` loop.  Other changes likely also needed.

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: BTW: `lens == leng` must be true, else code will have trouble with `secret[i] == guess[i]`.

Comment: I did write similar code a while years ago, you can glance at https://github.com/akrsnr/c/blob/master/sayiTahmin.c

Comment: You need two arrays to count digits, for example `scount[10]` and `gcount[10]`. Increment the appropriate digit counts when `secret[i] != guess[i]`. Then a second loop checks the digit counts. For example, if the digit 7 appears twice in `secret` and three times in `guess`, then add 2 to `pb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the number of the "first" string is equal to the "second" string at the current index, if yes increment, else iterate the "second" string to check if the current number from the "first" string is in the "second" string, if yes, increment

```
void get_score(char* secret, char* guess, int* peg_a, int* peg_b){
    int i, j;
    int pa, pb;
    pa = pb = 0;
    int lens = strlen(secret);
    int leng = strlen(guess);
    for(i = 0; i < lens; i++){
        if(secret[i] == guess[i]){
            pa++;
        }else{
            for(j = 0; j < leng; j++){
                if((secret[i] == guess[j])){
                    pb++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int k = i-1; k >= 0; k--){
                if(secret[i] == secret[k]){
                    pb--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

   *peg_a = pa;
   *peg_b = pb; 
}
```

The 3rd for is to check if the number that is now comparing is the same as one before

Comment: Still does not work right, but thank you for trying!

Comment: I think my mistake was not taking in consideration your program can have strings with repeated numbers in them, i already updated my answer that should handle those cases aswell

Comment: No problem, if my answer was what you wanted, please mark it as the correct one

Comment: @M3LeeOP Try it with "3322" and "2233".